# jQuery's hide and show methods not bubbling up calculated height in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, show

using: jQuery 1.7.1

I'm seeing an issue in IE8 where I have a container div that fails to calculate its height correctly when hiding/showing child elements(UL) inside of it using hide() and show().

This container div is a module body that wraps the module's content.   Our modules need to have a refresh method called each time something in the module need to adjust the height/width of the module, this is because they need a fixed height to render it correctly. It does this by grabbing the height of the container div, but when i expand or collapse inner sections in IE the container div doesn't recalculate its height.

I found out if I replace all the hide() show() with a .addClass("display-none") / .removeClass("display-none") (where .display-none{display:none;}) it fixes this issue.  However, I was hoping for a css solution where I can still use show and hide, some rule or IE issue/hack I don't know about.

**The question I want to ask is why?**

Here are some more details,

1. The items I am hiding and showing are groups of node from an in house built tree widget which is made up of nested unordered list, aka the hide and show are being applied to `<ul>`s.
2. I have another action the hides and shows elements with in a tree node, this action does cause the container div to recalculate its height correctly.
3. other divs that wrap the tree do recalculated correctly, it stops bubbling at the container div for some reason.

If code samples or html samples help I can provide that too, but I'm really looking to see if anyone happens to have a more general concept of what I ran into.

Here are the styles for the container

```
.module > div > div > * {
    word-spacing: normal;
}

.module-content-data {
    max-width: 962px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

.module {
    word-spacing: -1em;
}

Inherited fromdiv.main
.main {
    word-spacing: -1em;
}

Inherited frombody
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial,Calibri,Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually find a solution to this still haven't tracked down why. Apparently in IE8 $.hide() and $.show doesn't set calculated height correctly in some situations.  However, I modified my method to use an addClass("display-none") call instead and heights calculated correctly.  I hope this helps any other having a similar issue.

UPDATE:
On another page with this same issue the "fix" listed above had no effect.  So I still don't know. Will update if I find out more.